# The timestampsInSnapshots setting now defaults to true and you no longer need to explicitly set it

Tags: firebase, react-native

When i try to connect with fire-base database in react native it generate the error

My Code:

```
import * as firebase from 'firebase';
import firestore from 'firebase/firestore'
const settings = {timestampsInSnapshots: true};
const config = {
apiKey: "AIzaSyAKX2eSCZ1kqBgFdiNuZ-0Q",
authDomain: "studnt-db-4.firebaseapp.com",
databaseURL: "https://studnt-db-4.firebaseio.com",
projectId: "studnt-db-4",
storageBucket: "",
messagingSenderId: "1057776",
appId: "1:1053076:web:4638390e2d"
};
firebase.initializeApp(config);
firebase.firestore().settings({settings});
export default firebase;
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
firebase.firestore().settings({settings});
```

into this:

```
firebase.firestore();
```

You dont have to set `timestampsInSnapshots: true` since it is set by default

Comment: Hadded
Show Error as per your solution 
Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object.

Comment: just do this `firebase.firestore();`

Comment: Please dont share any keys like u did above u can make it marked as star ! Just a suggestion for avoding any data leaks or buffer